# How to set padding in styles for textviews in android?

Tags: android, styles, textview

In my android app, I want to create a style with has a padding property. I am using this:

```
<style name="title_numbering">
    <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#b60000</item>
</style>
```

java:

```
    TextView num = new TextView(this);
    num.setText(String.format("%d", index+1));
    num.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.title_numbering);
```

The textcolor seems to work, but the padding does not.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a close look at the `TextView`'s `setTextAppearance()` method, I realised that the `TextView` is not reading `padding` related attributes from `style`s. That is why padding from style will not work.

Here is the method from `TextView` for better understanding. The `applyTextAppearance()` method is called from the `setTextAppearance()` method.

```
private void applyTextAppearance(TextAppearanceAttributes attributes) {
    if (attributes.mTextColor != null) {
        setTextColor(attributes.mTextColor);
    }

    if (attributes.mTextColorHint != null) {
        setHintTextColor(attributes.mTextColorHint);
    }

    if (attributes.mTextColorLink != null) {
        setLinkTextColor(attributes.mTextColorLink);
    }

    if (attributes.mTextColorHighlight != 0) {
        setHighlightColor(attributes.mTextColorHighlight);
    }

    if (attributes.mTextSize != -1) {
        mTextSizeUnit = attributes.mTextSizeUnit;
        setRawTextSize(attributes.mTextSize, true /* shouldRequestLayout */);
    }

    if (attributes.mTextLocales != null) {
        setTextLocales(attributes.mTextLocales);
    }

    if (attributes.mTypefaceIndex != -1 && !attributes.mFontFamilyExplicit) {
        attributes.mFontFamily = null;
    }
    setTypefaceFromAttrs(attributes.mFontTypeface, attributes.mFontFamily,
            attributes.mTypefaceIndex, attributes.mTextStyle, attributes.mFontWeight);

    if (attributes.mShadowColor != 0) {
        setShadowLayer(attributes.mShadowRadius, attributes.mShadowDx, attributes.mShadowDy,
                attributes.mShadowColor);
    }

    if (attributes.mAllCaps) {
        setTransformationMethod(new AllCapsTransformationMethod(getContext()));
    }

    if (attributes.mHasElegant) {
        setElegantTextHeight(attributes.mElegant);
    }

    if (attributes.mHasFallbackLineSpacing) {
        setFallbackLineSpacing(attributes.mFallbackLineSpacing);
    }

    if (attributes.mHasLetterSpacing) {
        setLetterSpacing(attributes.mLetterSpacing);
    }

    if (attributes.mFontFeatureSettings != null) {
        setFontFeatureSettings(attributes.mFontFeatureSettings);
    }

    if (attributes.mFontVariationSettings != null) {
        setFontVariationSettings(attributes.mFontVariationSettings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to apply padding in drawable that will use it.

```
<item android:top="10px" android:right="10px">
```

**Edit :-**

Padding will have no effect on the shape.Instead write like this.

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:top="10px" android:right="10px" android:drawable="@drawable/myPic"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Do you mean this has to be in a shape tag?

Comment: after 8 years and 11 months, I got the same issue and it is not even close to the answer.